# Columns not being placed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use foundation in a rails app.  I have a row with two columns next to each other like the code below shows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns"> ... </div>
</div>
```

It works fine in development, but when I load it in the browser in production mode, the columns stack like a staircase instead of being placed in a row.  I've checked the CSS and saw that
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; }
is missing which I suspect might be the issue.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with checking if any CSS is loaded in You production environment.

How do You precompile assets? Check the precompiled assets on the production environment.

Where do You host Your app ? Without add-on enabled capistrano does not precompile assets automatically.